# Vigenere Cipher - Segmentation Fault

Tags: c, vigenere

I am trying to create a vigenere cipher and I am getting a segmentation fault. I am fairly new, and it would be highly appreciated if someone could help. Thank you in advance.

```
// Mukul Patel February 26, 2014
int my_key(string key)
{
    int key_length = 0;
    while (key[key_length] != '\0')
        key_length++;

    return key_length;
}

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2){ 
        printf("Please only enter two arguments which are non-numerical\n");
        return 1;
    }

    string key = argv[1];

    string plaintext = GetString();

    for (int i = 0, length = strlen(plaintext); i < length; i++){
        for (int j = 0, n = my_key(argv[i]); j < n; j++){
            if(isupper(plaintext[i]))
                plaintext[i] = ((((plaintext[i] - 'A') + (key[j % strlen(key)] - 'A')) % ALPHABET) + 'A');
            else if(islower(plaintext[i]))
                plaintext[i] = ((((plaintext[i] - 'a') + (key[j % strlen(key)] - 'a')) % ALPHABET) + 'a');
            else
                plaintext[i] = plaintext[i];

            printf("%c", plaintext[i]);
        }
    }    
    printf("\n");

return 0;
}
```

Comment: key: abcdabcd
plaintext: this is a test!

Comment: What is a `string` type? I haven't heard of one in C. What is `GetString`? Do you #include any files? Which are they? Are they standard ones? If not, what is their content? *In short: Please provide a ["short, self contained, compilable example"](http://www.sscce.org/).*

Comment: sorry, its part of a <cs50.h> library for a class. Just a training wheel for I guess, scanf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This: `my_key(argv[i])` in line `for (int j = 0, n = my_key(argv[i]); j < n; j++)`.

You accept only two arguments. So size of `argv[]` is 2. If `i>=2`, index of array goes out of bounds. So it may give segmentation fault error.

Comment: wow thank you so much, it makes sense now. I would have to change that to argv[1].